# Connect to snappy data with aws external IP address

Tags: snappydata

I am using Tibco ComputeDB, which is new to me. It uses sparkDB and snappyData. I can start both Spark and SnappyData and connect to snappydata using command **connect client '127.0.0.1:1527'** or with internal IP of aws server. But when I try to connect it with aws external IP using above command it do not work. Also I am not able to connect to snappyData from client like sql workbench/J. I have all required drives installed on local machine and server and also all ports are open on aws server. I can  access dashboard using http://externalip:5050.

I also edited conf/locators and conf/servers file as explained in below link and also hostfile entry seems fine.

=> https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/howto/connect_to_the_cluster_from_external_clients/

Lines were as below

=> "Private IP" -client-bind-address="Private IP" -hostname-for-clients="Public IP"

=> "Private IP" -client-bind-address="Private IP" -client-port=1555 -hostname-for-clients="Public IP"

I follow below document to connect with JDBC.

=> https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/howto/connect_using_jdbc_driver/

But still not able to connect with external IP.

=> connect client 'externalIP:1527'; should work before I can connect to snappydata from any client using external IP?

Can someone guide that what setting should be made to connect snappydata from aws external IP and with any sql client.

Answer (score 0):

Are the ports open for the public IP of the AWS instance itself? Right now that is needed if you connect using the public IP, even if you are trying to connect from the same AWS instance via `connect client ...` command.

Thumb rule is that ports (e.g. 1527-1528) must be open for the client's IP in the security group. So, if the client is in the same AWS instance, then ports must be open for it's *public* IP.

If this doesn't help, can you paste the content of files `locators`, `servers` and `leads` which are present under `conf/` directory? You can remove/strike sensitive information in them, if any.

Also please paste the error messages you see.

We have refined the steps to set up the cluster on AWS here that could clear a few things: https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/install/setting_up_cluster_on_amazon_web_services/#usingawsmgmtconsole